# On MAMP can I send php errors to a "per-test-site log"? Or must all errors go to MAMP/logs/php_error.log

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I have a number of test-sites running in MAMP/htdocs, do all of the errors for all test-sites have to go to the single `php_error.log`?  Can I change this? (I know I can change the log location in php.ini, but I see no way to "divide it up")

The trouble comes from installing "fire_log" logging Spark on one of my CodeIgniter test sites and it seems to want to look for log files relative to the Codeigniter Install.  That's what I'm thinking anyway, since it is not finding my logs.

I think it wants to see  `MAMP/CI_test_site/logs/php_error.log`

And I've obviously got

```
/MAMP
   /logs
       php_error.log
   /htdocs
       /CI_test_site
          /..folders
       /Other_site
       /DIfferent_site
```

So do I have any control over this in MAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set it on a per project basis from your code, if that's an option:

```
ini_set("error_log","/path/to/error.log");
```